# MVC5 Facebook Authentication - Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied#_=_

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

**Why am I able to successfully login via Facebook when debugging and running application as localhost but not after publishing to 1and1.com?**

I have been at this for almost a week. I have tried everything in every forum I've read with little success. The problem is, it is working when running as localhost, but fails when published to my production site. The production site is hosted by 1and1.com. What's confusing is I was able to authenticate in the production environment once; but not since. The entire project is almost all the default setup when creating a new MVC Web Application in visual Studio 2017. Here's the entire setup:

**Facebook App Settings:**

- App Domains: `smarthomeprodealer.com`
- Site URL: `https://smarthomeprodealer.com`
- Client OAuth Login: `Yes`
- Web OAuth Login: `Yes`
- Force Web OAuth Reauthentication: `Yes`
- Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs: `Yes`
- Enforce HTTPS: `Yes`
- Embedded Browser OAuth Login: `No`
- Valid OAuth Redirct URIs: `https://smarthomeprodealer.com/` `https://smarthomeprodealer.com/signin-facebook` 
  `https://localhost:44300/` `https://localhost:44300/signin-facebook`

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            { 
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = "*************",
            AppSecret = "*********************************",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie, 
            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = context =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                    foreach (var claim in context.User)
                    {
                        var claimType = $"urn:facebook:{claim.Key}";
                        var claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
                        if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Facebook"));
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl, string error)
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
            return this.View("Error");
        }

        var loginInfo = await this.AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to get external login info.");
            return this.RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var result = await this.SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return this.RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return this.View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return this.RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                this.ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                this.ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel viewModel = null;
                if (string.Equals(loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider, "facebook", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var identity = this.AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
                    var email = loginInfo.Email;
                    var firstName = identity.FindFirstValue("urn:facebook:first_name");
                    var lastName = identity.FindFirstValue("urn:facebook:last_name");
                    viewModel = new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel
                    {
                        Email = email,
                        FirstName = firstName,
                        LastName = lastName
                    };
                }

                if (viewModel == null)
                {
                    viewModel = new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email };
                }
                return this.View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", viewModel);
        }
    }
```

**packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Facebook" version="7.0.6" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="jQuery.MaskedInput" version="1.4.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.17.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.4.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

I successfully get Facebook's authentication window to open, but after clicking `continue` I get the following network calls:

General

```
    Request URL: https://smarthomeprodealer.com/signin-facebook?code=AQDBJtnrFRAOWXlsP-XwPpGYmOck3299lBcir6-W-1pK_jZDkKELCflt91yJ_RJQ5hChBUBgvxa6X-ZPxuCDiojdQOMiSOlxAdS6-3IUmGqCwfEqgROmnZF2WD3xsdZJNgRctbsR5-DPWcNUunB4Nmi0Z2fLPb6Cz7_kozK3MRRSuEiKDwfStUHeP_Hb07IZYXYQcDzq5XuR8FB-ZUDn4LLGoMgVQQ-O96FIvt7d_Yrm1_-THCk94HBdBRWlUyVXWBTFCssBZt7h5rE2lxqBnNREmEHXZgYaEDPDIAXA7Evp_M7tUu-BnkjJp1KojzXtcrcvCzV2oFflFy33gZr6kWvo&state=VctNDgrl9b6gQpcRUucyMLSWedxDOr6yhbmvlGRD37mWbVgAuW2p1nFbBkzJzIMjaXF65YKpKzEDiTYrSJDpVRnZIRyjiUnL-JW3Y6-evmerqysAezMENlneW3i3bvkH4f6BAvAMJw0C7SC6B2E2zlcGqvYJZvp0hlFqJbI1KhgMlozrChZcEFlYU0_leEXAp7JiwokC0ZloyRN9o3YA4siHolsHIR1tcOKnAoHSYaU
    Request Method: GET
    Status Code: 302 
    Remote Address: 74.208.236.203:443
    Referrer Policy: origin-when-cross-origin
```

Response Headers

```
content-length: 0
date: Fri, 24 Aug 2018 23:52:41 GMT
location: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
set-cookie: .AspNet.Correlation.Facebook=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
status: 302
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

Request Headers

```
:authority: smarthomeprodealer.com
:method: GET
:path: /signin-facebook?code=AQDBJtnrFRAOWXlsP-XwPpGYmOck3299lBcir6-W-1pK_jZDkKELCflt91yJ_RJQ5hChBUBgvxa6X-ZPxuCDiojdQOMiSOlxAdS6-3IUmGqCwfEqgROmnZF2WD3xsdZJNgRctbsR5-DPWcNUunB4Nmi0Z2fLPb6Cz7_kozK3MRRSuEiKDwfStUHeP_Hb07IZYXYQcDzq5XuR8FB-ZUDn4LLGoMgVQQ-O96FIvt7d_Yrm1_-THCk94HBdBRWlUyVXWBTFCssBZt7h5rE2lxqBnNREmEHXZgYaEDPDIAXA7Evp_M7tUu-BnkjJp1KojzXtcrcvCzV2oFflFy33gZr6kWvo&state=VctNDgrl9b6gQpcRUucyMLSWedxDOr6yhbmvlGRD37mWbVgAuW2p1nFbBkzJzIMjaXF65YKpKzEDiTYrSJDpVRnZIRyjiUnL-JW3Y6-evmerqysAezMENlneW3i3bvkH4f6BAvAMJw0C7SC6B2E2zlcGqvYJZvp0hlFqJbI1KhgMlozrChZcEFlYU0_leEXAp7JiwokC0ZloyRN9o3YA4siHolsHIR1tcOKnAoHSYaU
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: max-age=0
cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=S5Juj1hBkXIjmD-grTT7GznV6FrUMuyGCBmI5JoL9wXGoo3l9PKqscj54umCFGOSuK5pmx6Kjv8ap9QJ8q6ixNF2M9syQkq-iwDchS5m1u81; ASP.NET_SessionId=xaj1bb3qc5mzuefk3imxhhnl; .AspNet.Correlation.Facebook=pfQHMd0GIkxHeDwrLwGzcUdfmCUPPS2tR9G_WFPeueE
dnt: 1
referer: https://www.facebook.com/
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
```

**Why am I able to successfully login via Facebook when debugging and running application as localhost but not after publishing to 1and1.com?**

Comment: same problem here, running fine on staging and returns error=access_denied#_=_ on production

Comment: Hi, Did you manage to solve the problem? I have notice something that we both having the same hosting company "ionos" could it be the reason?

Comment: @HamdanDabbas I never did. I ended up putting the project on hold. I do still want to continue the project, this is where I'm stuck still.

Comment: Now I'm sure it's a hosting problem, the "ionos" team said they are not blocking anything from their side but I'm sure it's their fault, anyway I'm using the same methods and DLLs on GoDaddy hosting and it's working fine without any problem.

Comment: @HamdanDabbas Good to know. Thank you for that info.

Comment: Same problem here. In my case our site is self hosted. It was working fine in production a week ago. It also works fine in localhost.

Comment: @Tito I never did get this resolved. From all the research I did, it appears to be 1and1's servers that are the problem in my case. I wish I could be of more help.

Comment: @Paul, thanks. I tried to adding some diagnostic logging for Microsoft.Owin and ended up following error stack-trace:

Authentication failed
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationHandler.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__0.MoveNext() [Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationMiddleware]

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but after troubleshooting with the hosting team, they adviced me to put this in web.cofig and it worked!

`<system.net> <defaultProxy> <proxy usesystemdefault = "false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://ntproxy.1and1.com:3128" /> </defaultProxy> </system.net>`